# Protected questions not considering +100 bonus rep for linking profile

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, reputation, protected-questions

I have over 22k rep on various SE sites (mainly EE.SE) and received the 100 rep bonus when I came here for the first time and signed in.

[image]

However, I was prevented from answering a [protected question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/151480/music-files-dont-copy-from-itunes-to-iphone-appear-grey-with-a-dotted-circle?s=2%7C0.9009) because of insufficient reputation.

[image]

What gives? Since when is 101 less than 10? Is this a bug or by design? If it *is* by design, admins should update the protection note to clearly say that rep earned elsewhere doesn't count against the restriction.

Tried with two different browsers - same deal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).
The association bonus is purposefully removed from the calculation used to determine if you have sufficient reputation to answer a protected question.

To answer a protected question, you must earn 10 reputation specifically on this site, regardless of your reputation elsewhere on Stack Exchange.

There's already a feature request on Meta.SE to [change the phrasing of the protected question post notice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210481/improve-protected-question-message-with-regard-to-rep-gained-through-associati).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.